# conditional rewrite or try_files with NGINX?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

I'm having trouble setting up a conditional rewrite, and I've been trying to use the `if` directive (despite all sources indicating it's "evil") with the `-f` switch to check for the presence of a file, but it's not working. I believe the issue/case is best explained by example, so here goes:

#### Directory structure

```
workspace/
  myapp/
    webroot/
      index.php
      assets/
        baz.js
        hello/
          foo.js
    modules/
      hello/
        assets/
          foo.js
          bar.js
```

#### Expected results

```
/                     =>  /workspace/myapp/webroot/index.php
/assets/hello/foo.js  =>  /workspace/myapp/webroot/assets/hello/foo.js
/assets/hello/bar.js  =>  /workspace/myapp/modules/hello/assets/foo.js
/assets/baz.js        =>  /workspace/myapp/webroot/assets/baz.js
```

In summary:

- `foo.js` is only present in the `modules/hello/assets` folder and gets delivered from there.
- `bar.js` is present both in `webroot/assets/hello` and `modules/hello/assets` and gets delivered from `webroot`.
  (it hides/overrides the file in `modules`)
- `baz.js` is only present in `webroot/assets` and gets delivered from there.

The part that doesn't work right now, is this:

```
location /assets/ {
    if (-f $uri) {
        break;
    }
    root     /workspace/myapp/modules;
    rewrite  ^/assets/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/assets/$2 break;
}
```

Namely the `if` directive, doesn't seem to have any affect - the `bar.js` file gets delivered from `modules` rather than `webroot`.

Should I be using `if` or not?

Is there any way I can solve this problem with `try_files` instead? I can't seem to grasp how this would work together with `rewrite` which I can't seem to get around.

Please do not suggest reorganizing the assets using a deploy script or something - it's not an option, for various other reasons.

I have used this pattern with Apache before, and NGINX seems more capable in most respects, so I'm sure this must be possible?

One requirement that isn't absolute, is I don't *have* to be able to override `modules/hello/assets/foo.js` with `webroot/assets/hello/foo.js` - serving scripts from `webroot/assets/*` is however a requirement.

Comment: Your rewrite should use flag `last` not `break`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is divided into two parts: the first part explains why your configuration does not work and the second one provides examples of how to solve your problem. If you are only interested in the solution, go straight to the second part.

**The problem**

First of all, note that the positon of the `root` directive in a `location` block is not important. It does not matter if you put it at the very top or at the bottom of a `location`, it will affect the whole `location` anyway. Also, keep in mind that `break` in the end of the `rewrite` line tells Nginx to stay within the current location even if the URI has been successfully rewrited.

Having said that, let's take a look at your configuration and see how every request from the `Expected results` is processed and why nothing works as expected.

Let's presume that there is no other suitable `location` with a higher priority in your configuration. Since every request from `Expected results` starts with `/assets`, all of them will be handled according to the rules presented in your `location`. So:

1. `/assets/hello/foo.js`

The `root` is set to `/workspace/myapp/modules`. The `if` directive will be evaluated to false, because `/assets/hello/foo.js` does not exist and so `break` will not be executed. Finally, the last `rewrite` will change the requested URI from `/assets/hello/foo.js` to `/hello/assets/foo.js` and the following `break` will tell Nginx to stay within the current `location`. As a consequence `/workspace/myapp/modules/hello/assets/foo.js` will be served.

2. `/assets/hello/bar.js`

This request is processed exactly the same way as the previous one, so `/workspace/myapp/modules/hello/assets/bar.js` will be served.

3. `/assets/baz.js`

Yet again the `root` is set to `/workspace/myapp/modules` and the `if` is evaluated to false. But this time the final `rewrite` will not change the URI, because the request does not match the regular expression. As a consequence Nginx will try to serve `/workspace/myapp/modules/assets/baz.js` and since there is no such file exists, will return 404.

As you can see your configuration cannot possibly work as you want it to for several reasons:

- `if` is always evaluated to false, because you try to check URIs and not files;
- the request stays within the location because you tell it to stay there with `break` in the `rewrite` line;
- `root` is always set to `/workspace/myapp/modules` in this location so no file can be served from anywhere else.

**The solutions**

1. The easiest solution would be to use `try_files`:

   ```
   root /workspace/myapp/webroot;

   location /assets/ {
       try_files $uri @modules;
   }

   location @modules {
       root     /workspace/myapp/modules;
       rewrite  ^/assets/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /$1/assets/$2 break;
   }
   ```

   This configuration tells Nginx to look for a file in the `webroot` folder first and if nothing is found then go to the `modules` folder in another location. This approach is considered most preferable.
2. On the other hand, using `if` would allow you to solve the problem within one location:

   ```
   location /assets/ {
       root /workspace/myapp; # The parent folder

       if (-f $document_root/webroot/$uri) {
           rewrite ^(.*)$ /webroot/$1 break;
       }

       rewrite  ^/assets/([^/]+)/(.*)$ /modules/$1/assets/$2 break;
   }
   ```

   However, this approach is considered outdated is not recommended for use.

Comment: Thank you so much, @Ivan! Solution number 1 is very elegant and works perfectly! The ability to create locations with `@` that can't be accessed directly via a URL is indispensable - I didn't know about that one, this is going to be very useful! :-)